# re C++ range iterators: Is it bad to have just one class?

Tags: c++, iterator

e.g. should the following class be split into two:

```
class Range {
 public:
  Range(int end);

  Range begin();
  Range end();

  // Second class would contain these methods.
  bool operator!=(const Range& range);
  int operator*();
  void operator++();
};

// Print 012
// Almost as pretty as Python :D
for (int i : Range(3)) {
  std::cout << i;
}
```

?

PS: Is there a class like this in the standard library?

Update:

Here's what the alternative design would look like:

```
class Range;

class RangeIterator {
 public:
  bool operator!=(const RangeIterator& range_iterator);
  int operator*();
  void operator++();

 private:
  RangeIterator(const Range& range);
};

class Range {
 public:
  Range(int end);

  RangeIterator begin();
  RangeIterator end();

  friend class RangeIterator;
};
```

Comment: Not exactly, though there is `std::iota`.

Comment: I wonder how many times I can forget that exists. It's so useful. At least ranges are making their way to the standard library before long.

Comment: Can you add an example of the alternative into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd separate it -- the point of type-safety in C++ is that the compiler tells you off when you pass a range to a function that's supposed to take an iterator, or vice-versa. If the same class performs both roles then you lose this, and if `myrange` and `myrange.begin()` have the same type it's a realistic error to make. That said, since you like Python too you might not consider this a big deal, you're used to there being objects for which `__iter__` returns `self`. From a C++ POV I'd say that this would probably seem a bit unusual/tricky/clever.

It doesn't mean `RangeIterator` has to be publicly defined in your interface, though. You can use a typedef `Range::iterator_type`, backed by either a private nested class, or a class defined in a namespace. Either way, someone could inspect the class definition in a header file but you wouldn't document anything beyond "it can be referenced via the name `Range::iterator_type` and here's what you can do with it".

Speaking of which, neither `Range` nor `RangeIterator` currently satisfies the iterator requirements. If you ever decide you want your `Iterator` to be an iterator then you either need to specialize `std::iterator_traits`, add some typedefs, or (the common option) derive from `std::iterator`. So whichever way you do it, there's a bit more boilerplate to include. That might affect your decision. The more you have to write to start with, the less it costs you proportionally to define an extra class.

Here's `RangeIterator` turned into an iterator:

```
class RangeIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int> {
 public:
  bool operator!=(const RangeIterator& range_iterator) const;
  bool operator==(const RangeIterator& range_iterator) const;
  int operator*() const;
  RangeIterator &operator++();
  RangeIterator operator++(int);

 private:
  RangeIterator(const Range& range);
};
```

Comment: What does adding those base classes do? I think that the for loop works without adding base classes.

Comment: @allyourcode: `std::iterator` is there to help classes satisfy the so-called "iterator requirements" in the standard. A type that satisfies the requirements is commonly referred to as an "iterator". You're correct that the range-based for loop doesn't need an iterator, but having got half way there, it's not a bad idea to make your class be an iterator (especially for the version where it has `Iterator` in the name). Then you can use it with standard algorithms as well as the range-based for. Iterators are just "the C++ way", is all.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it should be split into two classes depends a lot on the context in which the software will be used.

For example, if the rest of the software has nothing to do with this type of code, maybe it makes sense, and reduces complexity, to keep things together.  On the other hand, if you are striving to have some sort of generic utilities, maybe it's better for maintainability (or arguably, for simplicity) to split things up.

Rather than have a hard rule for a snippet of code like this, I think you should think in terms of maintainability and readability.  Will your design choice make things easier to maintain in the long run?  Will it reduce the complexity of the project?

That's one of the cool things about architecting software!

Comment: I find that one of the annoying things about it, since I always think of the hard way first ;)

Comment: I suppose that could be a design objective in its own ;-)

Comment: My question basically boils down to "Which way is more maintainable?". One important aspect of this issue is "What do people expect?". If people (almost) always have two classes, I want to know that.

Comment: I think my point is that "maintainability" depends on the rest of your project.  In most cases, though, I would probably personally prefer to include it in one class.

Comment: So, you're saying "it depends". What does it depend on?

Comment: Read the second paragraph of my post.  If I'm writing this range utility to go in a program that does something a lot cooler, I'd prefer to keep it all in one class.  If I'm making a utility library, maybe I'll have separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll simple stick with second approach, it has some benefits:

1. You might want to traverse the `Range` in different ways, depending on what
   you want to accomplish. But you probably don't want to bloat the
   `Range` interface with operations for different traversals, even if you
   could anticipate the ones you will need.
2. Separating the traversal mechanism from the `Range` object lets us
   define iterators for different traversal policies without
   enumerating them in the `Range` interface. For example,
   `FilteringRangeIterator` might provide access only to those elements
   that satisfy specific filtering constraints.
3. You may want to provide polymorphism to `Range`, You can then
   generalize the iterator concept to support polymorphic iteration.